# How to upload PHP and MySQL web application on heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, phpmyadmin, heroku-postgres

I uploaded my PHP web app on Heroku, but it has a database, which I would like to upload too. I have exported the database into a .sql file from my local phpMyAdmin and created a ClearDB MySQL database on heroku.

What is the next step (or sequence of commands) of importing the existing database into CleaDB?

Comment: [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660521) saying "Here Tutorial to Upload php and mysql app to heroku: https://scotch.io/@phalconVee/deploying-a-php-and-mysql-web-app-with-heroku"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and configure SequelPro (mac) or [SQLyog](https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads) in windows to work with the database

Comment: Could you share more details. How to do it step by step please.